# Using Discord to accept input and execute on connected clients

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I currently have the Python Discord premade script to connect to Discord channel. I have it set up just fine and it works. I am able to create commands and make it do what I want. However I was wondering if it was possible to send a command like !dir, !net use, !wmic, etc on Discord and have it run on the connected client as if it was interacting with the machine directly. Like a shell, but through Discord?

My current code is the script found here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

I have been playing with doing this with sockets and using subprocess but not sure how to do this with the Discord API.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for.

```
if message.content.startswith('!cmd'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Enter command')
    msg = await client.wait_for_message()
    proc = subprocess.Popen(msg.content, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
    await client.send_message(message.channel, stdout_value)
```

Basically, once the bot detects that I say !cmd, it will ask for a command. Then I can enter ipconfig, net user, or whatever commands I want and the bot will execute them as if it was in a command prompt.